# Include video with \movie not working

Tags: beamer, texshop

I'm trying to embed a video in my latex presentation (using beamer).
I'm compiling latex within the TexShop.

When trying to embed this way, under the multimedia package:

```
\href{run:video/Tacoma.mp4}{\includegraphics[scale=0.12]{figure/video.png}}.
```

There are no problems, I click on the image and then it opens the appropriate video file. But since I need to include the video within the text (on the pdf file) I try with:

```
\movie[width=4cm,height=2cm,poster]{}{video/video.mp4}
```

but it displays a black area, and there is no video running even thought I click on it.

Do you know what the problem could be?
Maybe the pdf viewer in Mac? (I'm using the last version)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed in pdf viewer in Mac. If you install Adobe Acrobat Reader, you will be able to see embedded videos, independently from which compiler you used to generate your PDF.